# Cómo cambiar el tamaño del font de un text area, sin alterar el tamaño del text area

Tags: html, css

Estoy empezando en el mundo de la programación web y tengo una duda.

Cree una página para encriptar textos. Para capturar el texto que ingresa el usuario utilice un text area.
Quisiera saber como aumento el tamaño del texto sin alterar el tamaño de mi text area, con CSS. Porque cada vez que intento aumentar el tamaño del font también se aumenta el text area.
(Ya busque por Internet y no encuentro nada)
Espero me puedan ayudar :(

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo unico que necesitas es agregar un ancho o alto fijo a tu `textarea`

```css
.uno {
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 3em;
}
.dos {
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
.tres {
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 100%;
}
.cuatro {
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 4em;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="uno"></textarea>
<textarea class="dos"></textarea>
<textarea class="tres"></textarea>
<textarea class="cuatro"></textarea>
```

Estos son algunos ejemplos, espero te ayuden.